# Web and Http security config with JWT (ignoring login path problem)

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-security, jwt

I'm making an app with Spring security using JWT and react. However, it is behaving strangely. In the Configure file, which I did according to a tutorial, it says I need to ignore only the login paths. It works, I can login but after I obtain the token the config swears at me saying I can't access the path... I have the token now! How to fix it? My config files:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtInMemoryUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter;

    @Value("${jwt.get.token.uri}")
    private String authenticationPath;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(jwtInMemoryUserDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoderBean());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoderBean() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

       httpSecurity
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        httpSecurity
            .headers()
            .frameOptions().sameOrigin()  //H2 Console Needs this setting
            .cacheControl(); //disable caching
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
        webSecurity
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.POST,
                authenticationPath
            )
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .and()
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.GET,
                "/map-runner/", "/map-runner/static/**", "/static/**", "/map-runner/login", "/", "/login"
            );
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        ResourceResolver resolver = new ReactResourceResolver();
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(resolver);
    }

    public class ReactResourceResolver implements ResourceResolver {
        private static final String REACT_DIR = "/static/";
        private static final String REACT_STATIC_DIR = "static";

        private Resource index = new ClassPathResource(REACT_DIR + "index.html");
        private List<String> rootStaticFiles = Arrays.asList("favicon.ico",
                "asset-manifest.json", "manifest.json", "service-worker.js");

        @Override
        public Resource resolveResource(HttpServletRequest request, String requestPath,
                                        List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
            return resolve(requestPath, locations);
        }

        @Override
        public String resolveUrlPath(String resourcePath, List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
            Resource resolvedResource = resolve(resourcePath, locations);
            if (resolvedResource == null) {
                return null;
            }
            try {
                return resolvedResource.getURL().toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return resolvedResource.getFilename();
            }
        }

        private Resource resolve(String requestPath, List<? extends Resource> locations) {

            if (requestPath == null) return null;

            if (rootStaticFiles.contains(requestPath)
                    || requestPath.startsWith(REACT_STATIC_DIR)) {
                return new ClassPathResource(REACT_DIR + requestPath);
            } else
                return index;
        }

    }

}
```

I also use the server.servlet.context-path=/map-runner path in the properties.
The JWT implementation in other files is like in this tutorial repo https://github.com/in28minutes/spring-boot-react-fullstack-examples/tree/master/spring-boot-react-jwt-auth-login-logout/backend-spring-boot-react-jwt-auth-login-logout/src/main

Comment: Could you please provide specific information on the URL you are hitting and the error ?

Comment: I'm trying to access hocalhost:8080/map-runner/calculations this is the page that should appear after succesful log-in. I also have a server-side datatables get request there and this one says I need to provide the token (the custom message I set for these cases)

Comment: A JWT that is not expired should be part of each subsequent requests. also check if the jwtFilter is successfully authenticating the token on these requests